# lein deps exits when called from Dockerfile

Tags: maven, docker, dockerfile, leiningen

`lein deps` exits when called from a Dockerfile `RUN` command. Which means I can't preload my .m2 repository.

I ***can*** tty into the docker container and successfully run `lein deps` in the `WORKDIR`. But none of these commands work in a Dockerfile.

```
RUN lein deps
RUN /bin/bash -c 'lein deps'
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "lein deps"]
```

They all yield this error.

```
The command 'lein deps' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My Dockerfile looks like this.

```
FROM pandeiro/lein:latest

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN lein deps

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: show your Dockerfile

Comment: @user2915097 Absolutely - added.

Comment: I built locally pandeiro/lein:latest, but when is hte /app directory created?

Comment: I get `Couldn't find project.clj, which is needed for deps` when I launch `lein deps` after a `docker run -it --entrypoint bash  pandeiro/lein:latest`

Comment: Is your `Dockerfile` in the same directory as your `project.clj`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker's [best practices guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) recommends individually copying files that will be used by later Dockerfile steps. By initially copying just `project.clj` ahead of the rest of the files, I was able to run `lein deps` successfully.

```
FROM pandeiro/lein:latest

COPY project.clj /app
RUN lein deps
COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

(Also, [`pandeiro/lein`](https://github.com/pandeiro/docker-lein/blob/master/Dockerfile#L13) creates `/app` and sets it as `WORKDIR`, so I left out those steps.)